# Getting hasClass() or is() to look for one of multiple classes

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to get hasClass() to look for any of multiple classes?  I see people doing things like

```
if( ($(e.target).hasClass('box')) ||
    ($(e.target).hasClass('imgBox'))  ){
```

which would be much cleaner with something like

```
if( ($(e.target).hasClass('box imgBox')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if( ($(e.target).is('.box, .imgBox')
```